# How to return documents from a MongoDB collection with a "nested query"?

Tags: mongodb

I have a first collection "puzzles" with the documents

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5f08f168a9416800013a6259")}
{"_id" : ObjectId("5f1360a4abebae0001774d73")}
```

and a second collection "scores" with the documents

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f43d5998aa28c00017c2a1e"),
    "pId" : ObjectId("5f08f168a9416800013a6259"),
    "u" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5694fe24a57168f5fa3bbdaa")
    },
    "points" : 75
}
```

The field "pId" from the collection "scores" refers to the field "_id" from the collection "puzzles".

With one request, I want to get all the puzzles that are not referred to the "scores" collection for a given "u._id" (user Id).

How to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup` helps to achieve it.

1. First you need to get the matched document using `$match`
2. Then you can use *non co related queries* with `$lookup` where you can get non match documents using `$ne`

Mongo script is given below

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      "u._id": ObjectId("5694fe24a57168f5fa3bbdaa")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "puzzles",
      let: {
        pId: "$pId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                "$$pId",
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "notMatched"
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vbNaBl90NvU)**